# What was the heaviest example of horse armor (barding) from 16th and 17th centuries?

Tags: 17th-century, 16th-century, cavalry, records, armour

I would like to ask what the heaviest known example of armor for war horses is. Specifically, I'm asking about horse-armor in the 16th and 17th centuries (European, primarily, but I will accept other examples).

The answer I'm looking for is about horse-armor intended for warfare. However, I will accept answers relating to tournament armours.

The estimate I've seen for how heavy horse-armor is, is that [it was about as heavy as a knight's armor](https://www.quora.com/How-much-weight-did-a-warhorse-of-the-Middle-Ages-carry) (about 60 pounds tops, by his estimate). Is this accurate?

Comment: Keep in mind that "as heavy as a knight's armour" is itself a vague phrase with a wide possible range.

Comment: @Semaphore This is true. The link I posted goes into a bit more detail. Should I edit the post to clarify the range he stated?

Comment: Good idea. Generally best to avoid leaving information behind links because of link rot.

Comment: I have added in the person's estimate. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The heaviest example I could find was this outfit, which according to the photographer was on display at the [Zwinger museum in Dresden](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Dresdner_Zwinger) back in 2005. He said it was displayed as "16th or 17th century". The museum in question probably has some info on its weight.

[image]

However, from everything I could gather, this level of barding was uncommon by the 16th Century. Protective barding seems to have primarily been [a reaction to the longbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barding), as bowmen at battles like Crecy and Agincourt found they were able to defeat heavy cavalry by targeting their horses.

The Longbow [was on the way out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longbow#History) as an army's principle weapon by the beginning of the 16th Century, replaced by firearms. For whatever reason (I suspect lack of effectiveness against firearms) I cease to be able to find a lot of images of heavily barded horses after this point.

This nifty page on the [various types of barding](http://ilaria.veltri.tripod.com/overviewbards.html) is a good illustration of the point. All of the examples shown of full coverage barding are from the 14th century.